# Python capture substrings

Tags: python, regex

Please excuse my ignorance. I understand this is a very trivial question, but I'm having a lot of issue with regex.

I have a string like this:

```
Secret seed: SAI4OILKV6QNC24OMIVB4WWEBL7KQRV6L4CXOO5MSY6ONRXYPU5BYW6B
Public: GDOTL2NTFQ4XC3NDQLD33HNFS7FQBZ5CWVDIEQJNAKX2GRX5VH5CVVZA
```

I want to capture the secret key and the public key, so `SAI4OILKV6QNC24OMIVB4WWEBL7KQRV6L4CXOO5MSY6ONRXYPU5BYW6B` and `GDOTL2NTFQ4XC3NDQLD33HNFS7FQBZ5CWVDIEQJNAKX2GRX5VH5CVVZA` in this case. What is the regex is should be using to capture this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seeds seems to have a **fixed length** of **56 characters**, composed by **capital letters** and **numbers**, being so, we can construct a `regex` to match this type of pattern, something like:

```
text = """
Secret seed: SAI4OILKV6QNC24OMIVB4WWEBL7KQRV6L4CXOO5MSY6ONRXYPU5BYW6B
Public: GDOTL2NTFQ4XC3NDQLD33HNFS7FQBZ5CWVDIEQJNAKX2GRX5VH5CVVZA
"""
seeds = re.findall(r"\b[\dA-Z]{56}\b", text)
print(seeds)
# ['SAI4OILKV6QNC24OMIVB4WWEBL7KQRV6L4CXOO5MSY6ONRXYPU5BYW6B', 'GDOTL2NTFQ4XC3NDQLD33HNFS7FQBZ5CWVDIEQJNAKX2GRX5VH5CVVZA']
```

---

**Python Demo**:
 https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Q64

**Regex Demo**:
  https://regex101.com/r/7MKWEE/2

---

**Regex Explanation:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

It will match any string between word boundary preceded by ':'

```
:\s*?\b(.*)\b
```

> Explanation

- `:` - Matches character `:`.
- `\s? - Matches any space if there is.
- `\b` - Word boundary.
- (.*) - Matches any thing zero or more time except newline.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO9Sqz/1)